# If statement that affects another method in another class

Tags: java, class, if-statement

How do I setup an if statement that affects another method in another class in JAVA. So if a is 10 in Class A, than Class B will return true

Class A:

```
int a = 10;

public void Hey(){
if(a == 1){
System.out.println("one");
}else if(a == 10){
System.out.println("ten");
}
}
```

Class B:

```
A Obj = new A();

if(Obj.Hey()./*WHAT DO I PUT HERE*/){
    System.out.println("true");
}else{
    System.out.println("false");

}
```

Comment: `a` is a local variable. It's not accessible outside the `Hey()` method.

Comment: `a` do not exist after method is finished. It's locale variable that is initiated every time method `Hey()` is called and destroyed every time it is finished. You need class variable and `getter` to access that variable from `b` . Also I do not see any point in this code as `a` is changeable only in `Hey()` method I think you are asking wrong question. Do you know about class variables, constructors, getters, setters.. ?

Comment: But my question is how do I make it so that Class B's if statement prints true or false based on the condition of the if/else if statement in class A

Answer (score 2):

Return statement is needed to get result of method. See code below

**Class A**

```
 public boolean Hey(){
    if(a == 1){
    return true;
    }else if(a == 10){
    return false;
    }}
```

**Class B**

```
if(Obj.Hey()){
    System.out.println("true");
}else{
    System.out.println("false");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    int a = 10;
    public boolean Hey() {
        if (a == 10)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

class B {
    A Obj = new A();
    public B() {
        System.out.print(Obj.Hey());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B test = new B();
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
true
```